# Set statement_timeout on a per-user basis in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Postgres offers a way to set statement_timeout on a per-user basis through altering the role: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-alterrole.html

There is a known workaround to set the statement_timeout for a connection once it is established, but it would be helpful to set this at the role level.

Is there something available for YugabyteDB too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be already possible like in PostgreSQL. Example:

```sql
yugabyte=# ALTER ROLE yugabyte SET statement_timeout = 5000;
```

And then open another shell and try doing:

```sql
yugabyte=# select pg_sleep(5);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
yugabyte=# select pg_sleep(4);
 pg_sleep 
----------
 
(1 row)
```

Tested on 2.9.0.0